# Continue in level2

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I created a game where I have more scene, scene 1 = 1 level. When you get to level 2. How to make so I continued there even after the games?
I know that it is done by NSUserDefaults. But I do not know how.  Thank you

here is my code:

```
    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    let touch = touches.first as! UITouch
    let touchLocation = touch.locationInNode(self)
    let touchedNode = self.nodeAtPoint(touchLocation)

    if(touchedNode.name == "checkbutton"){
    if(inputText!.text == "motorka" || inputText!.text == "Motorka" || inputText!.text == "MOTORKA"){
    runAction(SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("correct.wav", waitForCompletion: false))
    correct.hidden = false
    inputText!.hidden = true
    check.hidden = true
    let nextLevel = level2(size: size)
        nextLevel.scaleMode = scaleMode
    let transitionType = SKTransition.crossFadeWithDuration(1.4)
    let wait = SKAction.waitForDuration(0.9)
    let action = SKAction.runBlock {
        view?.presentScene(nextLevel, transition: transitionType)
}

    self.runAction(SKAction.sequence([wait, action]))

}
else {
    unCorrect.hidden = false
    runAction(SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("Wrong-answer-sound-effect.mp3", waitForCompletion: false))
    delay(1.0) {
    self.unCorrect.hidden = true
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to figure out what data has to be transferred into your Level 2. Once you have that, you save the data you need in Level 1 (using NSUserDefaults as you already know) and then import the data into the beginning of Level 2.

In Level 1 let's stay you have an enemy with various properties like health, strength and weapon. One option you have is to save those 3 properties as strings, store them in an array (or dictionary) and save that in NSUserDefaults.

When you get to level 2, you read the NSUserDefaults, create your enemy and set the 3 properties.

There are MANY different ways of doing the above so my example is in no way the only method or the best method.

Comment: And after the game Switch Off, and turn on it again. The game will continue to level2?

Comment: @PeterSan - Not sure what you mean by switching the game off. If you are referring to your game remembering what level was last played then that too can be saved in NSUserDefaults. It is up to you to figure out, based on saved data, how and at what level to start play again.

Comment: @PeterSan - This explains it well. http://www.codingexplorer.com/nsuserdefaults-a-swift-introduction/

Comment: I created using NSUserDefaults when you reach Level 2 text writes me: NextLevel. But how to make of me save data when I turn off the game and start it again to continue to level2?

Comment: @PeterSan - I have no idea what you mean?!

Comment: Let's go from the beginning. I have quiz game. Run, you press PLAY and get level1, enter the correct answer and let me go to the next level. But when I turn off the game and will delete it from the multitask. Erases the achievement level and I have to play from level1.

How to save data by NSUserDefaults. So I turned in the game to continue in Level 2?

I'm sorry I'm a beginner but I learn ....

Comment: @PeterSan - There are a couple of ways to do this. 1) You save your data to NSUserDefaults every time there is a change (correct answer, increase level, etc...) 2) A slightly more efficient but harder way is to save your game state using the appDelegate method applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application. You will have to google this to get information on how to do this or ask a new question with this as the focus.